Building a flow to move data from Dataverse Table onto Azure Blob Storage using Power Automate
I built a basic powerapp with a data table and an edit form. Let's call this data table -Table1. With the submit form, I edit/write back content to the Table1. I want to build a flow that collects only the rows where I've modified values and overwrite these rows in the Azure Blob that I've created. This is how my flow looks.

This is the flow value at every step:


I saw in a lot of videos and posts here that the unique id is the one that has the sub heading- Unique identifier for entity instances. So that's what I chose.

And this is inside blob storage. My problems are that - even after I modify a row in the table in Dataverse, this flow isn't triggered at all.
Second, I feel there needs to be a way to store the multiple rows that are  modified from dataverse onto a separate place. And from there fetch it onto Azure Blob. ONLY the rows that have been modifed,not the entire table.
But I'm not sure where to look/ask for this.- This seems to be something that's basic and must have been demonstrated somewhere, but I can't find it.

Not quite sure why you're storing database rows in blobs, as blob storage isn't an indexable / queryable storage medium.

The Scope of the first action of your flow is set to User. This means the flow is only triggered when the record is modified by the user that is the owner of the record. Of course the flow should be turned on as well.
The solution here is to set the scope of the flow to Organization.
It is recommended to set additional trigger conditions, only in rare cases flows need to be triggered on any update.
See also Trigger flows when a row is added, modified, or deleted | MS Learn.

I already turned the flow on, and I set the scope to user because its mostly probably my account from which the rows will be updated/added.

But are you the owning user of the records you modified?

Oh,that I'm not. The blob is owned by another user. So you mean to say only he/she can trigger the  flow too?

Well, your flow is only triggered when that user modifies the record he/she owns. Set the scope of the flow to Organization when you need the flow to be triggered when a record is modified by any user. I updated my answer.

So I got the owner of the blob to trigger  this, but my flow still fails. I have given him access to the flow too. He has since come up with another flow, where instead of the get row by ID action, list rows>select>create csv table>apply to each>update blob, this works fine for him. Why is that?

I understand the flow is actually triggered now and your question is answered, isn't it? Probably the Row ID property of the Get action is not properly set. Just debug the flow to find out which property you need to use.
